# How to read output of USB type B port into arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, usbserial

I have an Arduino mega 2560 and I was wondering if it was possible to read MIDI data that is outputted from my MIDI keyboard. The USB type b port broke so I removed the port and wanted to know if I could directly connect the PCB contact pads to my Arduino and read the coming out. I could find no documentation on USB type B and what data is outputted by which contact pad.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no.

To do so you need to convert the USB protocol to something that Mega 2560 can understand (ex. SPI, RS232, etc.). You can check [USB_Host_Shield](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) and see if this can help you.